# Bootstrap Progress Bar with attached image on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

every one, perhaps this topic has been asked before but i surf a lot and didn't find any straight answer to this issue.

Problem: I need to have a progress bar that is filled simultaneously as the user is filling a form, and above of the progress bar I need an image be moving as well as the progressBar progress.

So, fill the progress bar as the form is being filled is simple, but I not quite handy as to manage moving the image with progressBar progress. 
This is html example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="progress_step1">
     <img src="img/step1.png" width="60" height="60" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="trial_banner col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 progress" style="padding: 0;">
     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-   valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:20%">
     <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can do something like `<div class="col-xs-3" id="progress_step1" style="left: 20%">`, same as with progress bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your comments I come up with a solution which I post in this codepen:
`enter code here`[Form & ProgressBar with Image filled simultaneously](http://codepen.io/d3n7s/pen/YqVKQE).

In my solution I had to comply with requirements as:

1. The ProgressBar won't advance if a form element isn't validated.
2. The ProgressBar won't advance if a form element was visited already, for example if an input has already been filled and you want to change the info.
3. After certain steps of the filling process the image has to change.
4. Up on completion of the form filling process the ProgressBar has to change color.
5. And of course, certain validation requirements for the elements on the form, for example: elements required, or phone number validation.

P.S: This solution is a partial of a bigger project, so that's why I use bootstrap and different js-plugins for easy form validation such as bootstrap-formhelpers, jquery-validate and additional-methods for jquery-validate.
Of course, any comments on how to make the code better will be most welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is using javascript, check where the user is on the form (Which input or how far they have scrolled or something) and use jQuery to change the information needed.